# Exercise on a function of a Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Let $g$ be the function
>
> $$ 
>  g(x) = (x-1)\,\mathbf{u}(x-1) + (x+1)\,\mathbf{u}(1-x)
>  $$
>
> Where $\mathbf{u}$ is the [unit step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) function. Let $X$ be a
>   standard  gaussian random variable, $X\sim N(0, 1)$, and consider
>   $Y=g(X)$. Compute che cumulative distribution function for $Y$.

**My attempt**

I noticed that rewriting the function $g$ one obtains

$$
\begin{align}
g(x) &= x\left[ \mathbb{u}(1-x) + \mathbb{u}(x-1)\right] + \mathbb{u}(1-x) - \mathbb{u}(x-1)\\
 &=x + \mathbb{u}(1-x) - \mathbb{u}(x-1)
\end{align}
$$

And the term $\mathbb{u}(1-x) - \mathbb{u}(x-1)$ evaluates to $1$ for $x< 1$, $0$ for $x=1$ and $-1$ otherwise. So my guess for the CdF for $g(Y)$ would be

$$
F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y) = 
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y\leq -1$} \\
\mathbb{P}(X-1\leq y), & \text{if $y\in(-1,f_{X+1}(0)]$}\\
\mathbb{P}(X+1\leq y), & \text{if $y\in(f_{X+1}(0), 1]$}\\
1, & \text{if $y > f_{X+1}(0)$}
\end{cases}
$$

Where $f_{X+1}(0) = \frac{1}{e\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Is my attempt close to the solution or my approach anyhow correct? If so, then computing the CdF explicitely is quite easy.

Comment: Note that $Y=y$, either if $X=y+1$ and $y>0$, or if $X=y-1$ and $y<2$, hence the PDF $f_Y$ of $Y$ is $$f_Y(y)=f_X(y+1)\,\mathbf 1_{y>0}+f_X(y-1)\,\mathbf 1_{y<2}$$ Passing by the CDF, by force, seems like a bad idea in the present case.

Comment: You are pleasantly right. Unfortunately the exercise wants me to compute the CDF though. Thank you I'll keep it in mind for later

Comment: Bad book then. $ $

Comment: BTW, which book is it?

Comment: Not a book, just an exercise from my professor